# Material UI submit button not getting triggered on Chrome but working on firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a login component with Reactjs and MaterialUI for styling,
The handleSubmit function is not getting triggered on Chrome but works on Firefox. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Below is my login component code, Does Chrome block Material UI event triggers?

This is all the details required for the question to be understandable.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';

import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';



const defaultTheme = createTheme();

export default function SignIn() {
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    console.log("hit here");
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    console.log(data);
    console.log({
      email: data.get('email'),
      password: data.get('password'),
    });
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
        <CssBaseline />
        <Box
          sx={{
            marginTop: 8,
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <Avatar sx={{ m: 1, bgcolor: 'secondary.main' }}>
            <LockOutlinedIcon />
          </Avatar>
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
            Sign in
          </Typography>
          <Box component="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
            <TextField
              margin="normal"
              required
              fullWidth
              id="email"
              label="Email Address"
              name="email"
              autoComplete="email"
              autoFocus
            />
            <TextField
              margin="normal"
              required
              fullWidth
              name="password"
              label="Password"
              type="password"
              id="password"
              autoComplete="current-password"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
              label="Remember me"
            />
            <Button
              type="submit"
              fullWidth
              variant="contained"
              sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
            >
              Sign In
            </Button>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs>
                <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                  Forgot password?
                </Link>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                  {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                </Link>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console when you click the button? If so please share

Comment: I'm using Chrome and I see that your code is working just fine (https://i.imgur.com/cQxYG3s.png). What exactly happens in your browser when you click the button?